# Update with CSV in PostGis

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am new to this postGIS concepts.. I have an postgres table in that i have some 10000 datas.Now i want to update some 100 datas in that table. I have this 100 datas in CSV file. SO i used the following query:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_x AS SELECT * FROM xxxxx LIMIT 0;

UPDATE xxxxxx
SET    latitude = tmp_x.latitude
USING  tmp_x
WHERE  xxxxxxxx.id = tmp_x.id;
```

But its showing error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "USING"
LINE 3: USING  tmp_x
```

What wrong with above query.Help me to solve this..Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a little syntax error. Should be "from" not "using".

```
UPDATE xxxxxx
SET    latitude = tmp_x.latitude
FROM  tmp_x
WHERE  xxxxxxxx.id = tmp_x.id;
```